# Save the ultimate expression in selectbox

Tags: javascript, textarea, expression

I wrote this code to save the expressions in a "memory" (textarea) in a select box, the code apparently works. 
I would, however, prevent to save an expression already present  in the select statement. In this case the code does not work. How so? It seems that there are no errors.

```
var flag = false;
for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].value == document.getElementById('textarea').value) {
       flag = true;
       break;
    }
}

if(!flag){
   select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(result, result); //salvo l'operazione in selectbox
   document.getElementById('operazione').disabled = true;
}else{
   alert("Memoria occupata");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function save() 
{
    var savedmemory = document.getElementById('operations');
    var expression = document.getElementById('code').innerHTML;
    var flag = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < savedmemory.options.length; ++i)
    {
        if (savedmemory.options[i].text == result)
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag)
    {
        alert("no.");   
    }
    else
    {
        //

        savedmemory.options[savedmemory.options.length] = new Option(result, result);
    }
}
```

`operations` is the reference toselect.
`code` to the textarea.